# Setting contet-length when using Writer?

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on some response wrapper. When `OutputStream` is used, i can determine the number of bytes. However, when `Writer` is used, I buffer the content as `char[]`, that is used later for writing to the output.

Its a bit noobie question, but how to be sure the real content-length when using `char[]` (i want to set the header - i know that I don't have to, but i want)? I mean, I could convert chars to bytes using used encoding and then flush bytes, but would like to skip another conversion.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the character encoding you are using:

- If you are using an 8-bit encoding (such as Latin-1), and you only have mappable characters to convert, then the character count is the same as the byte count.
- Otherwise, it is technically possible to work out how many bytes the character stream will encode to<sup>1</sup>, but there isn't a simple *and efficient* way to do it.

---

> Yeah, but that is a point, that I do not know the encoding in front and user may use anything. I don't see any other pragmatical way of doing this besides converting to byte[] - which probably happens under the hood, i guess.

Actually, it should be easy to tell what the the encoding is.  Call `getCharacterEncoding()` on the response wrapper.  If you do that after getWriter has been called, then it will be the encoding that was used to create the writer.  (At least, that is what the javadocs imply ...)

---

<sup>1 - For instance, with UTF-8 you would first implement a mapping of `char` values to Unicode code points, and then figure how many bytes are required to encode each code point.  This can be done without copying, etc, but you would need to code it from the ground up ... unless you can find a 3rd-party library that does this.</sup>

Comment: So your answer is basically to convert to `byte[]`?

Comment: @игор - Not necessarily.  See the footnote.  It depends on whether you are prepared to do some non-trivial research and coding.

Comment: Yeah, but that is a point, that I do not know the encoding in front and user may use anything. I don't see any other pragmatical way of doing this besides converting to `byte[]` - which probably happens under the hood, i guess.